# How to redirect output of a exe file to a QStringList in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

as the topic says can anyone tell me how do I redirect output of a executed exe to a QStringist variable so that I can display whatever the executed exe is doing in QTextBrowser in real time? For example if I execute a exe with simple echo command like this and say the exe name is hello.exe and its source code is as follows

`echo "Hello World!"`

And I execute it in Qt like this

`QProcess abc`

abc.start("files\\hello.exe);

Now this will echo the matter I feeded in source code i.e "Hello World" but as i am making a GUI app I cannot see it, so how can we take that output to a QStringList variable and display it in a QTextBrowser in real time? Are we allowed to have a multi-line output of the called exe? If the output of exe is very long and multilined and if it doesn't fit in QTextBrowser fully then does the scroll bar becomes visible automatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**According to QT documentation (please read it):**

You bind your handler to `QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput ()`, which will be emitted every time process has new data available on STDOUT. Then you use `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput ()` to fetch the data. Then you convert byte array to `QString`, paste it with the remainder of the previous splitting and split it by delimiter and fill `QStringList`. Then you output it to `QTextBrowser`.

Comment: Ohk.. can you please explain it with code? I understood the logic but as I am a beginner I cannot rectify my problem in terms of code. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but no, I dont have time to write working code for you. I already described what you need to do. If this sounds gibberish to you, you are welcome to look it up from Qt documentation. API's I referred to are in the same class, which starts your program. If you dont know how QProcess works, then you should read about it before touching. People should help to help them, not asking to do their work with vague specification

Comment: I have made a new question for that pls have a look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921004/cannot-read-output-using-readyreadstandardoutput-in-qt#comment15874358_11921004

It isn't working :(