# Cannot read output using readyReadStandardOutput in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using Qt and I am unable to get output of a exe file using readyReadStandardOutput.

Here is my code.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_24_clicked()
{
    myprocess = new QProcess(this);
    myprocess->start("files\\helloworld.exe");
    connect(myprocess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput ()), this, SLOT(outlog()));
}

void MainWindow::outlog()
{
    QString abc;

    abc = myprocess->readAllStandardOutput();

    emit outlogtext(abc);
    ui->lineEdit_4->setText(abc);
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QProcess *myprocess;

signals:
    void outlogtext(QString ver);

private slots:
    void outlog();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The helloworld.exe will just give a output "Hello world" but I cannot see it in the textEdit, whats wrong with my code? I am very new to Qt. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that outlog() is slot, not just a function?

Comment: I think yes, I have added mainwindow.h also on the 1st post. Please have a look.

Comment: You should append the text, not replace it, as the output could come in multiple chunks or even an extra readyRead might be emitted to indicate the closing of the pipe.

Comment: Also make sure helloworld flushes stdout in case it doesn't terminate immediately after printing.

Comment: I tried putting java.exe and in process I put java -version and I expect version number in textBrowser which I don't get
Tried append, no effect :(

Comment: Also tried only echo hello, still no output :(

Comment: Try to connect to the finished and error signals (before calling start, just in case) to make sure your program is actually successfully started. Also add the code of your helloworld.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the program working. Below is the code.

**mainwindow.hpp**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void outlogtext(QString ver);

private slots:
    void outlog();
    void on_pushButton_24_clicked();

private:
    QPushButton* pushButton_24;
    QLineEdit* lineEdit_4;
    QProcess *myprocess;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    pushButton_24 = new QPushButton;
    connect(pushButton_24, SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(on_pushButton_24_clicked()));

    lineEdit_4 = new QLineEdit;

    QWidget* central = new QWidget;
    QLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(pushButton_24);
    layout->addWidget(lineEdit_4);
    central->setLayout(layout);
    setCentralWidget(central);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_24_clicked()
{
    myprocess = new QProcess(this);
    connect(myprocess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
            this, SLOT(outlog()));
    myprocess->start("./helloworld.exe");

    // For debugging: Wait until the process has finished.
    myprocess->waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << "myprocess error code:" << myprocess->error();
}

void MainWindow::outlog()
{
    QString abc = myprocess->readAllStandardOutput();
    emit outlogtext(abc);
    lineEdit_4->setText(abc);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   MainWindow win;
   win.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

**helloworld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Some things I changed:

- After constructing an object, I always connect signals and slots before performing the
  actual operation on the object, which might be calling `show()` for widgets or calling
  `start()` for threads. So I can be sure that I do not miss a signal like `started()`,
  for example.
- I ran the program on Linux. There I had to make sure that `helloworld.exe` was on my
  path and I changed the command to `./helloworld.exe`. I didn't create the sub-directory
  called `files` as in your example.
- The character to separate directories in Qt is the slash `/`. There are special functions to convert between the Qt-style and the native-style, when you want to display something to the user. Internally always make use of slashes. This even works for Windows programs (many console commands can cope with a slash instead of a backslash, too).
- Adding debug output is really, really valuable during development. If the Makefile is
  not set up correctly or something breaks, the `helloworld.exe` might end up in a directory, where it is not expected. Thus, I added code to wait for some time until the process has finished. This does not hurt because `helloworld.exe` needs just some milliseconds to run. Afterwards, I print the error code of `QProcess` just to be sure that the program has been found and could be executed. So I can be sure that the executable is on my path, that the executable flag is set, that I have permissions for executing the file etc.

I don't know exactly what causes the problem on your machine. However, comparing your solution to mine, having a look at the error code of `QProcess` and setting break points inside the slots should help you finding the error.

Comment: Thank you very much!!
I got it working, actually my exe was having problems and I figured it out using qdebug as you showed. Excellent Thanks a lot!